# Reading a Open Loop Current sensor

Tags: current-measurement, hall-effect

I am using a [LEM HAIS 200-P](http://www.lem.com/docs/products/hais_e_rev11.pdf) and I never have worked with Open Loop current sensors before.

I have some questions about the datasheet:

1. What is the difference between Primary nominal RMS current and
   Primary current measuring range?
2. If I can force some Vref, so how's the offset fixed? It will change
   as I force the Vref, right?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between Primary nominal RMS current and Primary
>   current measuring range?

Both are per-part number metrics.  They both relate to full scale measurement range for a device.
"Primary nominal RMS current" is the recommended max RMS current.  It is also used in the equation for V<sub>OUT</sub>.
"Primary current measuring range" is the max DC current that can be resolved.

> If I can force some Vref, so how's the offset fixed? It will change as
>   I force the Vref, right?

The datasheet indicates that you can force V<sub>REF</sub> to be between 1.5V and 2.8V; it is nominally 2.5V.  V<sub>OE</sub> is defined as V<sub>REF</sub> +/- 0.025V, so yes, as you change V<sub>REF</sub> you will change the output offset (V<sub>OE</sub>).

Comment: But the application notes says it's fixed offset..http://www.amds4.com.br/web/img/CH24108E_US.pdf

Comment: So if I am only working with DC current, how's the output formula? Ipn = Ip, so Ipn*Tp will always be equal to 1?

Comment: Could you point out exactly where the app notes indicate fixed offset?  This would seem to contradict the datasheet.  In your second follow-up question, what's Tp?

Comment: Sorry..it was kinda late in here...I made a typo..it was supposed to be "Ipn/Ip".
In page number 9 you can read "Gain and offset are fixed." (search for it using Ctr+F, it's easier)

Comment: That application note is specific to the HSX models, which are different from the datasheet you posted.

Comment: AFIK the application note speaks about all the 3 models...HXS (page 5), HAIS(page 9) and HTFS (page 11)

Comment: @mFeinstein, the document speaks to all 3 models, but the fixed offset comment is specific to the HXS:  "As for the HXS models, the reference voltage (internal or external) is found at the output for no primary current (*). Gain and offset are fixed."

Comment: Well, english is not my main language, so I understood the "As for the HXS" as "as we have said about the HXS models, HAIS are the same"..it's wierd speaking of HXS in the HAIS page...I guess I am wrong right?

Comment: I read the "Technical Information" note to say that the HXS, like the HAIS, produces an output of VREF when there is no current. ("Duh"). The HXS apparently has a fixed gain and offset, which might or might be like the HAIS. However the HAIS datasheet does say fixed offset and gain, and I think that is semi misleading. The Electrical data table shows that the unit _provides_ a _VREF_ that is fixed (and available via a pin), OR you can supply your own "MyVREF" (into the VREF pin) and that will force the offset to your VREF.

Comment: "Ipn = Ip, so Ipn*Tp" ... "supposed to be 'Ipn/Ip'"  Not sure what you are getting at here. Perhaps you are asking what the output voltage would be for a particular DC input current? My reading is you get VREF+0.625V for full scale. So, for the Ipn=100A unit, you would get VREF + 0.625Vrms for 100Arms input, and, I'd assume, VREF + 0.625V DC for 100A DC input.